# Error Importing .wrl file with Blender

Tags: python, error

Whenever I try to import a wrl file which is a 3D map from Surfer, it shows me this error below.

This is an image showing the error

[image]

Comment: Do other .wrl files work for you?
Does the file work in other contexts than blender?